# Возможно ли ObjectId (MongoDb) конвертировать в строку на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

C сервера уходят данные и там есть id с типом данных ObjectId. На клиенте он приходит в таком виде:

```
Object {
   timestamp: 1476891401, 
   machine: 13949887, p
   id: 10700, 
   increment: 3401974, 
   creationTime: "2016-10-19T15:36:41Z"
}
```

Если использовать .toString(), то получается "[object Object]".

Action:

```
    public JsonResult GetPictures(int page = 0)
    {
        int count = 12;

        IMongoCollection<Photo> collection = DBConnection.GetInstance().GetCollection<Photo>("Photos");
        List<Photo> pictures = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Skip(page * count).ToList().Take(count).ToList();

        return Json(pictures);
    }
```

Model Photo:

```
public class Photo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string[] Categories { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конвертировать у меня не вышло, решил вопрос так:

```
public JsonResult GetPictures(int page = 0)
{
    int count = 12;

    IMongoCollection<Photo> collection = DBConnection.GetInstance().GetCollection<Photo>("Photos");
    List<Photo> pictures = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Skip(page * count).ToList().Take(count).ToList();

    var pics = pictures.Select(x => new { id = x.Id.ToString(), x.Name, x.Path, x.Categories, x.DateTime }).ToList();

    return Json(pics);
}
```

В action добавил строку:

```
var pics = pictures.Select(x => new { id = x.Id.ToString(), x.Name, x.Path, x.Categories, x.DateTime }).ToList();
```